# How to recursively chmod directories with space characters in their names

Tags: linux, command-line, chmod

```
find . -type d | xargs chmod 770
```

Doesn't work, gives 'No such file or directory'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want simply to do the recursion, use `-R`.

```
chmod -R 770 dir_path
```

Is this what you want:

```
find . -type d | xargs -I {} chmod -R 770 "{}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but only directories should be effected

Comment: @user1981297 If it works for you, please, accept the answer as valid. To accept an answer, click on the tick mark, right below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `print0` option of `find` to deal with spaces in filename

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs chmod 770
```

Why not just use the `-R` option:

```
chmod -R 770 dir
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to mention only dirs should be 770, files should be 644

Comment: Doesn't make total sense, if the directory can't be read by everyone why would you give the file read permission.. anyway use `print0` see update.

Comment: That still gives 'No such file or directory' shouldn't the be double qoutes somewhere?